# Undefined is not an object while trying to query nested objects. Using axios and React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, axios

The JSON response is as shown in the image 1.
I was able to assign the entire response using axios (which already does the `JSON.parse`) to the state (named profile).

while `profile.bio` and `profile.image` are working;
`profile.user.username`, etc are not working and throwing an error - `Undefined is not an object`

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
const phone_no = phone.phone;
const fetchProfile = useEffect(() => {
var res = {};

axios
  .get('<API URL>' + phone_no)
  .then((response) => (res = response.data))
  .then(() => {
    setProfile(res);
  })
  .then(() => console.log(profile))
  .catch((e) => console.log(e)); });



const user_stream = {
    name: first.first_name,
    image: profile.image,
    id: profile.user.id,
  };
```

Update - Solution: Using async-await with axios, it's fixed.

Comment: with the data on the image you posted it should work... or post your code to check there isn't a bug

Comment: Please put code samples in the body of your post, not as an image link.

Comment: added code, see user_stream - image: profile.image is working; but not id: profile.user.id

Comment: The question is (now?) confusing, because it references an *image 1*, but there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`profile` or `profile.user` may still be undefined when trying to access it, so `profile.bio` is just undefined so it doesn't cause an error, but `profile.user.username` tries to access a property of an undefined object.

Try adding `profile?.user?.username`

Or `profile && profile.user && profile.user.username`

This will ensure that it only tries to render the username if profile is already defined

Comment: `profile.bio` works cause `profile is instantiated as an empty object so while the actual profile is being fetched `profile.bio` would return undefined and react wont render anything for that split second, then once the actual profile is returned the `bio` is populated as now `profile.bio` has a value, however if you try to access `profile.user.username` while profile is still an empty object it throws an error because you are trying to access the `username` property of an undefined object `user` since it doesn't yet exist on the `profile` object. I Hope this makes sense

Comment: Yes, got it what you mean.